# Static DHCP / DHCP Reservation on D-Link WBR-1310 rev B?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm trying to set up static IPs for a few devices on my home network. I've read a few websites, and for D-Link, people are saying to look for Static DHCP under:

`Setup > Network Settings > Static DHCP`

But there is no option for this. I just updated my firmware, and on that page, all I see is "Router Settings", "DHCP Server Settings", and "Dynamic DHCP Client List".

Was static IP "not around" in 2007? It seems I didn't get what I paid for with this free router. Is there any other way I can get this to work? I need to have a static IP on my wireless printer.

I have WPA-2 enabled, and my SSID is unhidden/broadcasting.  My router is a D-Link WBR-1310, rev B.  Firmware version is 2.02.

Comment: Your router model/version number might be helpful.

Comment: If it was a free router, then you didn't pay for anything ;) Static DHCP was around well before 2007, and I'd be highly, highly surprised if your router didn't support it, so you can probably rest easy on that front. However, a model # is necessary to give you proper steps to configuring static IPs for devices on your network.

Comment: Perhaps it is referred to as "DHCP Reservations"

Comment: @DarthAndroid It's a Dlink WRB-1310 with firmware 2.02 (newest)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I looked for that, too. I've searched every settings pane, and I haven't found anything yet

Comment: Without doing my own digging on the make/model just yet, I'd bet @DarthAndroid has it right.  Though DHCP Reservation is by far not a new concept, not all SOHO routers (and, especially not older routers) have the feature available in stock firmware.

Comment: Also, FYI:  This option is sometimes referred to as "Static Lease".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then. As best I can tell, there's no configuration for that particular model to have DHCP reservations. Your best bet would be to see if you can run an alternate firmware on the device, such as DD-WRT or OpenWRT or Tomato. It's not that the hardware can't do it, they simply didn't put in a way to configure the software to do what you want.

Comment: Found my way around to D-Link's emulator page for this router.  http://support.dlink.com/emulators/wbr1310_revB/202/lan.htm  Looks like you're right.  I can't find DHCP reservation settings anywhere either.  If custom firmware is not a desirable option, consider getting a new router.  Most modern routers support this feature.  Every Linksys router I've had in the past few years does.

Comment: @IsziRoryorIsznti okay, I'll probably get a new one when I can. It seems so ridiculous, though. Could they just "forget" to add SSID support? Definitely avoiding dlink like the plague when I buy a new one. But in the mean time, how safe and easy is custom firmware? In the little research I did, it seems like it requires soldering and programming ROM chips, is this true?

Comment: @lucase.62 Oh no. If it's supported, it really should be just going through the usual firmware update methods, simply with a non-Dlink firmware. You download the alternate firmware, go to `Tools -> Firmware`, select the custom firmware, and upload it. Make sure to do your research that the firmware does support your device though-- It can be a real pain to "unbrick" (restore) your router if a bad firmware image is uploaded and doesn't boot up properly or doesn't support the router.

Comment: +1 again to Darth Android, and congrats to him on 10k!  Most routers (WRB-1310 included) have a "firmware upgrade" function built-in to the web interface.  Usually this is used to install updates from the manufacturer, but it can also be used to install custom firmware you download.  Just be extra-vigilant in reading the documentation of the firmware you select, making sure the firmware is indeed compatible, and following the instructions.  You might also want to make sure you have extra room in your budget at the time you do this, in case you do actually "brick" the router.

Answer (score -2):

You do not configure static ip addresses on the router, you configure them on the device.

Check your printer manual on instructions on how to set a static ip

On windows go to Start>Control Panel>Network connections. Right click on Local area connection and click properties. Scroll down to Internet Protocol and click properties.

Click the radio button for use the following ip address and then type in the IP information you want to use.

Comment: This is not what the OP is requesting.  Setting static IPs on the device will make it difficult for the device to easily travel between networks.  What the OP is referring to (albeit by incorrect terminology) is "DHCP Reservation".  With DHCP Reservations, the DHCP server keeps an IP address assignment reserved for systems by their MAC address.  That way, systems with reserved IPs will always get the same IP when they reconnect - even though they're still using DHCP.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about static DHCP, where the DHCP server reserves and always assigns the same IP to a device based upon its MAC address, as opposed to a static IP configured on the device.

Comment: Why would he want his printer to travel between networks?

Comment: @VBwhatnow The OP first said it's "for a few devices", *then* mentioned his printer as an example.  I wouldn't be surprised if the other devices include a laptop or something equally as mobile.  In any case, the user specifically asked for how to use DHCP to enforce "static" IPs.  Your answer does not address that.  Besides, if you were assuming that this was only for a printer, why did you include Windows instructions?